# An uncountable and closed subset of the Liouville Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, closed-form, diophantine-approximation

I am trying to "find" a closed and uncountable subset of the Liouville's numbers.

$x\in L$ means that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ exists $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $q>1$ such that $$0<\vert x-\frac{p}{q}\vert <\frac{1}{q^n}.$$

Ideas are welcome!!

Comment: Any sum of the form $\sum_n \epsilon_n 2^{-n!}$ where $\epsilon_n \in \{0,1\}$ and $\epsilon_n = 1$ for infinitely many $n$ should be Liouville.  Maybe you can find a closed uncountable set within these numbers?

Comment: I studied the subset of $A={\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{x_n}{y^{n!}} : y\in\mathbb{N} \text{ , }x_n\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots,y-1\}}$. This set $A$ is contains in $L$ and in no numerable. But is not close.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following set should work:

$$A = \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n 2^{-n!} : \epsilon_n \in \{0,1\} \text{ and } \epsilon_{2n-1} + \epsilon_{2n} = 1\right\}.$$

The additional restriction that the sequence of $\epsilon_n$s consists of $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ pairs ensures that every element of $A$ is Liouville.  Furthermore I believe that every convergent sequence in $A$ has each $\epsilon_n$ eventually constant, which means the limit point also satisfies the defining property of $A$.

Comment: @JonathanOrtiz No, $A$ is uncountably infinite which is very, very far away from two.  There are $2$ choices for each pair $(\epsilon_{2n-1},\epsilon_{2n})$, and countably many $n$ for a total of $2^{\aleph_0} = c$ points.

Comment: The set $L$ of Liouville numbers is a dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of the reals.(It is also Lebesgue-null,)  The space $L$ is completely metrizable (because it's $G_\delta$ in the completely metrizable space $R$), and has no isolated points (as it's dense in $R$). So it has a subspace homeomorphic to  the Cantor set. Thus we infer the existence of a set like $A$  but without an explicit example. ..I like your Answer.